# How to clone database tables with constraints in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a few tables with relations to one another (foreign keys).
Inserting rows fails unless it takes the constraints into account.

I can disable the constraints only on a specific order, create the new tables, add the data and rebuild 
the constraints but that is a lot of work to do and I want to avoid it.
Is there a way to clone a group of tables with their data in a simpler way?

Comment: Maybe you need deferred constraints

Comment: From oracle : Once you've added a constraint, you cannot change it to DEFERRABLE. You must drop and recreate the constraint.

Comment: I agree with Aleksej - the constraints need to be deferrable. Unfortunately, if an existing constraint is not deferrable, you can't "alter" it to make it deferrable. Fortunately, you can get the DDL to (re-)create the index relatively easily; with that in hand, you may drop the existing index and recreate it, but make it deferrable and initially deferred.

Comment: so there is now way to clone it? these are existing tables I cannot alter.
so recreating the new tables with deferrable constraints and then inserting the data would do ?